# How to invert a matrix with transfer functions in python?

Tags: python, numpy, matlab, controls, linear-algebra

I know that in matlab I can do the following:

```
s = tf('s')
G11 = (s + 1)/(s + 2)
G12 = 1/(2*s + 1)
G21 = 1/(3*s + 1)
G22 = 1/(4*s + 1)

A = [G11 G12; G21, G22]
Ai = inv(A)
bode(A)
```

and it will work just fine. In python, I tried to do something similar:

```
import control as co
import numpy as np

s = co.tf('s')
G11 = (s + 1)/(s + 2)
G12 = 1/(2*s + 1)
G21 = 1/(3*s + 1)
G22 = 1/(4*s + 1)

A = np.array([[G11, G12], [G21, G22]])
Ai = np.linalg.inv(A)
co.bode(A)
```

But this doesnt work - numpy doesnt know how to invert this matrix.

Is there a good way to do this in python? I know that I can use scipy with s being a symbol, but I think that doesnt help me when using the others tools in the control toolbox.

Edit:

numpy returns the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UFuncTypeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-ec46afd90eb6> in <module>
     10 
     11 A = np.array([[G11, G12], [G21, G22]])
---> 12 Ai = np.linalg.inv(A)
     13 co.bode(A)

<__array_function__ internals> in inv(*args, **kwargs)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py in inv(a)
    543     signature = 'D->D' if isComplexType(t) else 'd->d'
    544     extobj = get_linalg_error_extobj(_raise_linalgerror_singular)
--> 545     ainv = _umath_linalg.inv(a, signature=signature, extobj=extobj)
    546     return wrap(ainv.astype(result_t, copy=False))
    547 

UFuncTypeError: Cannot cast ufunc 'inv' input from dtype('O') to dtype('float64') with casting rule 'same_kind'
```

Comment: "numpy doesnt know how to invert this matrix" bold assumption there, my friend. Alternative: you don't know how to make numpy to what you want.

Comment: You are supposed to explain why you think it doesn't work. If your computer catches fire when you do it, or if there is an error, of if the numbers are not what you want, the solutions will be different.

Comment: Thank you, I'll edit the post to insert the error that numpy returns

Comment: Is that 2x2 case the only case you are interested in?  Or will you also be using larger matrices?

Comment: I ask because for a 2x2 matrix, it is easy to find the inverse without any external library.  If A is `[[a, b], [c, d]]`, the inverse is `[[d/det, -b/det], [-c/det, a/det]]`, where `det = a*d - b*c`.

Answer (score 4):

Numpy (hint: it's right in the name) is a numerics library only; it does not do symbolic math. Sympy (also in the name) does symbolic math, so use it:

```
import sympy

s = sympy.Symbol('s', imaginary=True)
g11 = (s + 1)/(s + 2)
g12 = 1/(2*s + 1)
g21 = 1/(3*s + 1)
g22 = 1/(4*s + 1)
A = sympy.Matrix((
    (g11, g12),
    (g21, g22),
))
sympy.pprint(A.inv())
```

with output

```
⎡    3       2                       3       2              ⎤
⎢ 6⋅s  + 17⋅s  + 11⋅s + 2      - 12⋅s  - 31⋅s  - 15⋅s - 2   ⎥
⎢ ───────────────────────      ──────────────────────────   ⎥
⎢     3      2                      3      2                ⎥
⎢  6⋅s  + 7⋅s  - 3⋅s - 1         6⋅s  + 7⋅s  - 3⋅s - 1      ⎥
⎢                                                           ⎥
⎢     3       2                 4       3       2           ⎥
⎢- 8⋅s  - 22⋅s  - 13⋅s - 2  24⋅s  + 50⋅s  + 35⋅s  + 10⋅s + 1⎥
⎢─────────────────────────  ────────────────────────────────⎥
⎢     3      2                      3      2                ⎥
⎣  6⋅s  + 7⋅s  - 3⋅s - 1         6⋅s  + 7⋅s  - 3⋅s - 1      ⎦
```

Comment: Thank you, this helps but my main goal was to use python to analyze this system - bode plot, check stability, etc, so I think this solution still isnt what I was looking for

Comment: @DavidDaminelli numpy is a python library. Simpy is a python library. If your goal is to use python, you will be using it by using this solution.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `control.tf` returns an object of class `control.TransferFunction`. This is different from the MATLAB version that returns a symbolic function object.

By looking through [the documentation](https://python-control.readthedocs.io/en/0.9.2/generated/control.TransferFunction.html#control.TransferFunction), I don’t see a built-in way to convert a `control.TransferFunction` object to a symbolic function object, but I did see there are the `num` and `den` methods, you could construct a symbolic function using those values. And then you can apply [the answer by Reinderien](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74276060/7328782).